# Boolean union fails to delete internal geometry

Tags: modifiers

[image][image]I fairly frequently run into problems with boolean unions not deleting the internal geometry. I often resort to going through and cleaning it up by hand, but I feel like there should be a better way, and this one would be a bit taxing to do manually.
Both structures are solid, fully manifold objects, they don't share any faces, and I have recalculated the normals on both of them.
I took a picture with it lifted up out of the object because its too much of a mess in wireframe mode, but when I do the boolean modifier you can clearly see the point of the support still exists inside the object below, and I would have to go through and clean them up all the way around the circle.
Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: Union is doing the work it is assigned to! What you want do exactly!

Comment: You probably need to use Difference in place of union!

Comment: Union is not supposed to leave behind internal geometry, It is supposed to merge the two into one solid object, deleting any parts that are inside each other.
Difference would not join my two parts together, it would carve a hole in the bottom part for each one of the top parts, and leave them separate.

Comment: Do you have ref image of what you want to do?

Comment: In the image I provided, the pieces to the left and right of the raised piece are in the position I want. That is what I want them to look like on the outside. But when I join them blender leaves behind the small point of each support inside the main piece, and It generates 2 faces separating the 2 parts from each other, so when I go to 3d print it the printer will be confused and not know how to handle those internal pieces. I will try to take some pictures.

Comment: I have added a picture taken from the inside. In the back you can see a point as blender is leaving it, in the middle of the picture is one where I have deleted most of the undesired geometry by hand. There is still one face in the corner that shouldnt be there, and there is a faces still separating the two object from each other. I need both gone, so it is just one external envelope around both objects.

Comment: In which object do you add boolean modifier, the main or the other one?

Comment: I think boolean bugs sometimes, but maybe share your file?